# Django sqlmigrate command?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

According to this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/

It seems they are adding an sqlmigrate command.

Anyone has any idea of the features? Is it as powerful or better than South?

Comment: I believe it's Andrew Godwin (creator of South) who is leading the effort on providing database migrations to Django. So I imagine it'll be just as functional. Here's the Kickstarter that Andrew ran in order to provide the funding for the [project](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/andrewgodwin/schema-migrations-for-django). There's a link to a pull request on that page for the initial changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [a whole chapter on the new migrations feature in Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/). You will find there everything you need to know.

Andrew Godwin, the creator of both South and the new Django feature, also made [a series of blog posts](http://www.aeracode.org/category/south/) describing how it works. He also gave [a talk on migrations](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JXGW56CGsCM) during DjangoCon US 2013.

Comment: That's just a link.  Why not answer the question?

Comment: @RClaven it's to broad to answer in a different way! I assume Lucas Tan is familiar with general idea of migrations, since he mentions South. He asks specifically about the futures, and to answer this I would basically need to repeat the whole chapter in Django documentation. I don't see the point.

Comment: Touche.  I suppose in my fatigue last night I was just telling you what others have told me.  Grumpy b**tard, I am.

BTW - they wont let me un-vote unless you edit it.  The rules here are not always ideal.

Answer (score 12):

with this command you can see sql query related about each migration files :

**command structure**

```
python manage.py sqlmigrate <app_name> <migration_file_name>
```

**example :**

```
python manage.py sqlmigrate app 0003
```

**result :**

```
BEGIN;
--
-- Add field golabi to test
--
CREATE TABLE "new__app_test" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "golabi" varchar(100) NULL, "name" varchar(100) NOT NULL, "test" varchar(100) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO "new__app_test" ("id", "name", "test", "golabi") SELECT "id", "name", "test", NULL FROM "app_test";
DROP TABLE "app_test";
ALTER TABLE "new__app_test" RENAME TO "app_test";
COMMIT;
```

you can use this command for **examine your project generated migrations**.